# Как посчитать одинаковые символы в строке Kotlin

Tags: строки, kotlin

Задача состоит в том, что в консоль вводится любая строка данных (readln). И небходимо реализовать программу, которая выведет всевозможные символы данной строки и напишет сколько раз каждый символ в ней встречался.

Я не пойму, как сделать подсчет кол-ва всех букв.

```
val str = readln()
val countA = str.count { it == 'a'}
println("количество символа А - $countA шт")
```

Comment: 1. сначала счётчик равен нулю. 2. когда условие выполняется, счётчик увеличивается на единицу. 3. profit.

Comment: Задача на языке Kotlin решается в одну строчку: `"Hello".groupingBy { it }.eachCount()`. Вывод: `{H=1, e=1, l=2, o=1}`

Answer (score 1):

В стандартной библиотеке Kotlin для этого есть функции [`groupingBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/grouping-by.html) и [`eachCount`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/each-count.html):

```kotlin
"Hello".groupingBy { it }.eachCount()
```

Вывод:

```
{H=1, e=1, l=2, o=1}
```